# Watchkit failed to upload to App Store

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, watchkit, ipa, submission

I'm using Application Loader 3.1 and i've found that these messages happened because Apple was not accepting watchkit. Nowadays Apple already accepts them so i don't know why i'm getting theses errors. Some help?

[image: Uploading ipa]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Xcode 6.2 adds the *.app to your Bundle Resources. This causes the errors.

You should go to Project->Targets->App->Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources and delete the *.app file.